# Prevent users from Router 2 seeing Router 1 computers

Tags: networking, routing

I've got 2 Netgear N300 (WNR2000v3) routers.

Here's my setup:

Modem > Router 1 > Private Users/Router 2 > Public Wireless Users on "Guest" Network.

I want to prevent users who are connected to Router 2's "Guest" network from accessing anything that is connected to Router 1. There is an option when setting up the "Guest" network called "Allow guest to access My Local Network" which I thought if unchecked would do this very thing; however, I can still access files and such of computers connected to Router 1.

Router 1 assigns 192.0.0.x IP addresses, Router 2 assigns 10.0.0.x IP addresses, how can they even see each other? Do I need to change the subnet or something else?

Comment: Some routers can have guest wireless network, that probably what is that setting about. You should use this feature instead of stacking routers.

Comment: In your case  Guest network have full access to network for private users because... NAT. same way how Private users can access Internet... Btw, in your setup "Private" users dont have access to guest network :)

Comment: This is a sort of DMZ, DMZ is nearer to internet. put the public user near modem.

Comment: I don't want to use the "Guest Wireless Network" as I want to set throttling so as they can't use all my bandwidth.

Answer (score 5):

Put a filewall between Router 2 and Router 1. Allow traffic from router 2 to go only to the internet.

Comment: Do you mean like a physical firewall box, or something software related?

Comment: A physical box. Either a firewall box or a computer with two NICs running firewall software.

Answer (score 0):

The best way i can think of is swap router 2 with router 1. so let the public network be first, then the private network. Machines is public area will not be able to connect to private area because of NAT. One issue would be some MITM attacks as internet data of private network would flow through public network.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to achieve this goal is to make sure that Router 2 has a default gateway that points directly to the ISP providing Internet access.  That should actually be the only route in the routing table for Router 2. Also Router 2 should not be running any active routing protocol or exchanging any routing information with Router 1.

Comment: I will try this out when I get home today, thanks for the suggestion.